# How to get visitor group name in SharePoint using c#?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, permissions

I need to get the visitor group name of the SharePoint site in c#.please suggest any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code:

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
Group visitorGroup = web.AssociatedVisitorGroup;
```

You can also try below method:

```
int idOfGroup = Convert.ToInt32(web.Properties["vti_associatevisitorgroup"]);
SPGroup group = web.SiteGroups.GetByID(idOfGroup);
```

Or iterating through the site groups as below:

```
public static SPGroup GetVisitorsGroup(SPWeb web)
{
    if (web.Properties["vti_associatevisitorgroup"] != null)
    {
        string idOfVisitorGroup = web.Properties["vti_associatevisitorgroup"];
        int visitorGroupId = Convert.ToInt32(idOfVisitorGroup);

        foreach (SPGroup group in web.SiteGroups)
        {
            if (group.ID == visitorGroupId)
            {
                return group;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Reference - [Get visitor group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437430/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-3-permission-groups-visitors-members-owner)